# Laravel merge duplicate object in array

Tags: javascript, loops, duplicates

This is my output query:

```
array = [
   0: {brand: "Samsung", phone_unit: "J7 pro"}
   1: {brand: "Samsung", phone_unit: "S9"}
   2: {brand: "Samsung", phone_unit: "S7"}
   3: {brand: "Iphone", phone_unit: "iphone 6s"}
   4: {brand: "Iphone", phone_unit: "iphone X"}
]
```

This what I want to happen:

```
array = [
   0: {
        brand: "Samsung",
        phone_unit: ["J7 pro", "S9", "S7"]
      }
   1: {
        brand: "Iphone",
        phone_unit: ["iphone 6S", "iphone X"]
      }
]
```

how can I do this output using *map* or in *ES6* javascript

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by reducing your array to an object grouped by `brand` and then calling `Object.values` to get the final array:

```js
const array = [
   {brand: "Samsung", phone_unit: "J7 pro"},
   {brand: "Samsung", phone_unit: "S9"},
   {brand: "Samsung", phone_unit: "S7"},
   {brand: "Iphone", phone_unit: "iphone 6s"},
   {brand: "Iphone", phone_unit: "iphone X"}
];

const result = Object.values(array.reduce((acc, {brand, phone_unit}) => {
  if (!(brand in acc)) acc[brand] = {brand, phone_unit: [phone_unit]};
  else acc[brand].phone_unit.push(phone_unit);
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```